# HTTP Content-Length header has 1 byte too many

Tags: php, apache, http, http-headers, content-length

I'm writing a (PHP) script that serves files to the client. Among others, the Content-Length header is sent, only it has one byte too many. I discovered this when I put the content length in a different header, and compared the two:

```
$filesize = filesize($file);
header('Content-Length: ' . $filesize);
header('X-Content-Length: ' . $filesize);
```

Result:

```
Content-Length: 3481
X-Content-Length: 3480
```

Even when hard-coding `3480` into the `header()` function, this is the outcome. I suspect Apache doing this to my headers.

What might be causing this?

Edit: To give some context: I think Zend Framework is causing this: I'm refactoring code that is currently in production (and working) to ZF, where the problem occurs. When I try this code outside of ZF, all is well. Maybe ZF is doing output buffering, and re-sending the headers itself or something, but I don't really know ZF that well.

Comment: Which value is the correct one?

Comment: maybe your script prints 1 symbol before content of file. try to write `ob_start();` in the first line and `ob_end_flush();` before output content of file.

Comment: @Alvaro 3480, the custom header is left alone, the actual content length header is obviously modified before sending.

Comment: It's suspicious that the difference is only one byte. Is it possible that's an Unicode text file and Zend is adding a BOM? Have you compared the file before and after with a file compare tool? Are you using HTTP compression?

Comment: Thank you OZ_, you put me on the right path. Zend uses output buffering, and a couple PHP files started with a space. When I removed that, it worked. +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not Apache's doing, but a space before a PHP open tag in combination with output buffering.